# Gitlab-runner permissions

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

Trying out gitlab and trying to build a simple create-react-app project. However, I'm having issues with the gitlab-runner. I'm running gitlab on an EC2 instance using the AMI from gitlab that's in the amazon marketplace.

by yml is really basic.

```js
build-site:
  image: node:9
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - build
```

However the output I get in the gitlab web UI is

```js
Running with gitlab-runner 10.1.0 (c1ecf97f)
  on runner-1 (9fc6bc1c)
Using Shell executor...
Running on ip-10-214-239-156...
Fetching changes...
warning: failed to remove builds/0/project-0.tmp/git-template/config
warning: failed to remove builds/0/project-0/.istanbul.yml
warning: failed to remove builds/0/project-0/yarn.lock
warning: failed to remove builds/0/project-0/src/Root.js
warning: failed to remove builds/0/project-0/src/utils/common.js
```

and the output I get when running `sudo gitlab-runner --debug exec shell build-site` when ssh'ed into the ec2 machine

```js
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
FATAL: exit status 1
```

Comment: there is a gitlab-runner user which the runner uses make sure you add that gitlab-runner to the root group and the user group

Comment: I don't see a gitlab-runner user. Is one supposed to be created automatically? Or is it meant to be a manual process?

Comment: it will be created when you install gitlab-runner

Answer (score 3):

had to add user `gitlab-runner` to docker group

`usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner`

seems to have done the trick

Comment: Do you add this line to "script" section in gitlab.yml?